# How to properly update this field in struct in C

Tags: c, struct, updating

trying to remember the syntax for updating a pointer in a struct.
I have something like this for example.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
}car;
```

And I have a function which is called

```
void update_Name(car *d, char *newname)
{
    car->name = &newname;
}
```

Is that correct or would it just be simply newname?
Very straight forward dont worry about any other syntaxes or functions needed just wanted to know straight up how that would be updated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That is not quite correct.

You have a `char *newname` function parameters. You have a `char *name` struct member. `&newname` creates a pointer to newname which would be `char **`. Not what you want.

You just want `car->name = newname;` That assigns a `char*` to a `char*`.

Always be sure to compile your programs with maximum warning levels. It will tell you when you assign mismatched pointers.

And also in code like this remember memory and pointer lifetimes. You are assigning a pointer to characters into a structure. Whatever that points to needs to survive at least as long as your `car` structure or your `car->name` will become a "dangling pointer" pointing to dead memory.

Answer (score 0):

First, `car->name` is not correct because `car` is the name of a type, not a variable.  You want `d->name` instead.

With that correction, the type of `d->name` is `char *`.  You're attempting to assign an expression of type `char **` to it which doesn't match.

`newname` is already of type `char *` which matches the type of `d->name`, so you can assign it directly.

```
d->name = newname;
```

Comment: oh ok and if i have for example in the struct an int k and in the function an int f, i can just do car.k = f?

Comment: @John `d->k=f` actually, since `car` is the type and `d` is the variable, and since `d` is a pointer.

Comment: oh yea sorry i meant d not car,

Comment: What if im trying to update a double pointer array for example can i do       
apple[a].size = size      if the function im in had an (int size) parameter and ofc a parameter passing the double pointer array?